# Converting VARCHAR to DATE in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a data flow task in a SSIS package that loads data into a table from a flat file.

In the source data, there is a date column in the format DD/MM/YYYY, and I am trying to convert it to YYYY-MM-DD and convert it to a date. The expression in my Derived Column task is:

```
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING(SaleDate,7,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(SaleDate,4,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(SaleDate,1,2))
```

However this task fails with the below errors:

```
Error: 0xC0049064 at Load into Staging, Derived Column [2]: An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.
Error: 0xC0209029 at Load into Staging, Derived Column [2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[SaleDate2]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC0047022 at Load into Staging, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Derived Column" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Derived Column Input" (3). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC02020C4 at Load into Staging, Flat File Source [12]: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
Error: 0xC0047038 at Load into Staging, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

Here is my expression editor:

[image: expression editor]

I understand that this is probably quite a common issue but in searching for an answer I've not found anything that helps.

Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: I usually use script component and .Net DateTime.ParseExact Method

Comment: @Piotr could you go into a little more detail? I've never used script in SSIS before

Comment: Try: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56911/ssis-convert-ddmonyyyy-dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue eventually myself, after attaching a data viewer to the derived column task, I realised that the date column had double quotes in the source file. I adjusted my SUBSTRING parameters to compensate and the import is working now.

Comment: Sounds like what you actually should have done was specify the text qualify in your Flat File Connection. Then the value wouldn't be wrapped with quotes.